# Amazon Dynamo DB Persistent ORM

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, data-access-layer

I am trying to create a generic wrapper library(C#/.NET) for AWS DynamoDB which can act as DAL(Data Access Layer). The applications consuming this library will not be tightly coupled with AWS libraries as there is a possibility that it can be changed later.

The structure of methods to be exposed from wrapper class are 
***InsertItem< T>(object)*** , ***UpdateItem< T>(object)*** , ***DeleteItem< T>(id/object)***, 
***List< T> GetAll()*** , ***T GetByParameter< T>(Id)***.

I see that there are three approaches to consume AWS DynamoDB services using AWSSDK.

***Approach (1) :*** Low level Access - convert model to aws hashmap input structure and invoke getItem()/putItem() .

***Approach (2) :*** High Level Access using Document - convert model to aws document model and passing document object to aws.

***Approach (3) :*** High Level Access using Persistence - Using attribute DynamoDBTable in model to map model to dynamoDb table and using linq operation to get/update table.

In approach(1) & (2), i find it difficult to map the model to dynamoDB table. In approach (3), I see that i need to include the DynamoDB attributes in model class in application which would make it tightly coupled.

Is there any way to create mapping in runtime in this cases or is there any other approach?

I also thought whether i can json serialize/deserialize the model and inset into dynamoDB(In this case there would be only 2 columns - id, json body for any model).

Please correct me if i am wrong or missing something.

Comment: We have been writing to Dynamo but not reading. Using Persistence model, we have a generic class at the DAL (let's call it Log<T>) that has the SDK attributes and the application can pass in any class it wants and it will get set in the T property on the Log<T> object.

Unfortunately, I am now trying to read that data and it is proving difficult with Persistence since I want to see all logs, regardless of the T used on the write.  Making a separate read class with T replaced with string, object, or Document has not worked.  Will try non-Persistence for reads and will update if successful.

Comment: Thanks for updates. Let me know if you got any other information.

Answer (score 3):

What follows is the solution I'm moving forward with, minus some extraneous details.  The biggest challenge is reading data of arbitrary types, since you can't easily tell just from the JSON.

In my solution, the consuming application that chooses the types to write also knows how to identify which type to deserialize to when reading.  This is necessary because I need to return multiple logs of different types, so it makes more sense to return the JSON to the consumer and let them deal with it.  If you want to contain this in the DAL, you could add a Type column in the DB and convert it using Reflection, though I think you'd still have issues returning data for multiple types in one call.

The interface we present for consumption has read/write methods (you can add whatever else you need).  Note that writing allows specification of T, but reading requires the caller to deserialize, as mentioned above.

```
public interface IDataAccess
{
    Task WriteAsync<T>(Log<T> log) where T : class, new();
    Task<IEnumerable<LogDb>> GetLogsAsync(long id);
}
```

A LogDb class contains the Persistence attributes:

```
[DynamoDBTable("TableName")]
public class LogDb
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey("Id")]
    public long Id{ get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty(AttributeName = "Data", Converter = typeof(JsonStringConverter))]
    public string DataJson { get; set; }
}
```

A generic Log<T> class used for strongly-typed writing.  The ToDb() method is called in the IDataAccess implementation to actually write to the DB.  The constructor taking in a LogDb would be used by a consuming application that had identified the appropriate type for deserialization:

```
public class Log<T>
    where T : class, new()
{
    public Log() { }

    public Log(LogDb logDb)
    {
        Data = licensingLogDb.OldDataJson.Deserialize<T>();
        Id = licensingLogDb.Id;
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public LogDb ToDb()
    {
        string dataJson = Data.Serialize();
        return new LogDb
        {
            DataJson = dataJson,
            Id = Id
        };
    }
}
```

The JsonStringConverter used in the attributes on LogDb converts the JSON string in the DataJson property to and from a DynamoDB Document:

```
public class JsonStringConverter : IPropertyConverter
{
    public DynamoDBEntry ToEntry(object value)
    {
        string json = value as string;
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(json)
            ? Document.FromJson(json)
            : null;
    }

    public object FromEntry(DynamoDBEntry entry)
    {
        var document = entry.AsDocument();
        return document.ToJson();
    }
}
```

A helper class provides the Serialize and Deserialize extensions, which use JSON.NET's JsonConvert.Serialize/Deserialize, but with null checks:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static string Serialize(this object value)
    {
        return value != null 
            ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value) 
            : String.Empty;
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string json)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json) 
            ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)
            : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic method convert Dynamo table to c# class as an extension function.

```
public static List<T> ToMap<T>(this List<Document> item)
    {
        List<T> model = (List<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<T>));
        foreach (Document doc in item)
        {
            T m = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            var propTypes = m.GetType();
            foreach (var attribute in doc.GetAttributeNames())
            {
                var property = doc[attribute];
                if (property is Primitive)
                {
                    var properties = propTypes.GetProperty(attribute);
                    if (properties != null)
                    {
                        var value = (Primitive)property;
                        if (value.Type == DynamoDBEntryType.String)
                        {
                            properties.SetValue(m, Convert.ToString(value.AsPrimitive().Value));
                        }
                        else if (value.Type == DynamoDBEntryType.Numeric)
                        {
                            properties.SetValue(m, Convert.ToInt32(value.AsPrimitive().Value));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (property is DynamoDBBool)
                {
                    var booleanProperty = propTypes.GetProperty(attribute);
                    if (booleanProperty != null)
                        booleanProperty.SetValue(m, property.AsBoolean());
                }
            }
            model.Add(m);
        }
        return model;
    }
```